# Variations of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, limits

I understand that 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e
$$

However, how would $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{3n}\right)^{5n} $ be simplified.

The $5$ can be moved outside the limit:

$$
{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{3n}\right)^{n}\right]^5}
$$

But how can you simplify it to the form $e^{\frac{m}{n}}$?

The answer is $ e^{\frac{5}{3}} $, but could someone help me understand the methodology?

Comment: $\left\{\left(1+\frac{1}{3n}\right)^{3n}\right\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a subsequence of $\left\{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right\}_{n\geq 1}$, hence it converges to the same limit, $e$. Given the continuity of $x\mapsto x^{5/3}$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$, your limit equals $e^{5/3}$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't move $5$. Move $5/3$ instead: 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{3n})^{5n}=\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{3n})^{3n}\right)^{5/3}.$$
You will find the inside limit is $e$.

Answer (score 6):

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{3n})^{5n} =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} ((1 + \frac{1}{3n})^{3n})^{5/3}= e^{5/3}$

Answer (score 3):

Everybody has given the solution, but this is how it hit me,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\biggr(\bigg(1+\frac{1}{3n}\bigg)^n\biggr)^5$$

Let $$3n=t$$

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\biggr(\bigg(1+\frac{1}{t}\bigg)^{\frac{t}{3}}\biggr)^5$$

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\biggr(\bigg(1+\frac{1}{t}\bigg)^t\biggr)^\frac{5}{3}$$

$$e^\frac{5}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{3n}\right)^{5n}=e^{5n\log \left(1 + \frac{1}{3n}\right)}\to e^{5/3}$$

indeed

$$5n\log \left(1 + \frac{1}{3n}\right)=\frac53\cdot\frac{\log \left(1 + \frac{1}{3n}\right)}{\frac1{3n}}\to\frac53 \cdot 1 = \frac53$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the most general case of
$$y=\left(1 + \frac{1}{an}\right)^{bn}$$ Take logarithms
$$\log(y)=bn\log\left(1 + \frac{1}{an}\right)$$ Now, use Taylor series
$$\log(y)=bn\left(\frac{1}{a n}-\frac{1}{2 a^2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \right)=\frac{b}{a}-\frac{b}{2 a^2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Use again Taylor
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=e^{\frac{b}{a}}-\frac{b e^{\frac{b}{a}}}{2 a^2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.